# vba - write text to sfile path does not work error

Tags: vba

With the help of Userforms and textboxes, i can add new personnel to my personnel file, but there is something wrong in my code and the code does not work. I do get an error while carrying it out. The error says "Compile error: Method or data member not found". I dont know what is wrong with my code, my expectations are that i fill in some Textboxes and i want them added to the already existing seq file (Notepad). But it doesnt let me do that and i dont know why.

I would be happy if someone can find the problem and give a solution.
Thanks in advance.
If you need code from other Commandbuttons,Userforms,etc.. Please tell me.. I dont know entirely what to publish now.

I have already tried changing the Userform_Nieuw names, but to no avail.

```
Private Sub seq_bestand_maak_databank()

Dim diploma As String
Dim pad As String

pad = "C:\Users\fhaka\Downloads\Overzicht_Personeelsleden.txt"

If UserForm_Nieuw.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    diploma = "Secundair"
ElseIf UserForm_Nieuw.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    diploma = "Bachelor"
ElseIf UserForm_Nieuw.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    diploma = "Master"
End If

If CInt(nieuw.Label1.Caption) = 1 Then
    Open pad For Output As #1
Else
    Open pad For Append As #1
End If

Write #1, CInt(UserForm_Nieuw.Label1.Caption), UserForm_Nieuw.Voornaam, UserForm_Nieuw.Naam, CInt(UserForm_Nieuw.Aantal_kinderen), UserForm_Nieuw.Geboortedatum, UserForm_Nieuw.Startdatum, "---N/A---", diploma, "0", "---N/A---", "---N/A---", "EOR"
Close #1

End Sub
```

The goal is that the commandbutton works again and that i can add more personnel now.

Comment: You say *there is something wrong in my code and the code does not work*, but you don't explain any problem with the code. What **specifically** is *wrong* with your code? In what way does it *not work* as you'd expect? What does your having *tried changing the Userform_Nieuw names* have to do with anything? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Hello @KenWhite. I do get an error while carrying it out. The error is Compile error: Method or data member not found. I dont know what is wrong with my code, my expectations are that i fill in some Textboxes and i want them added to the already existing seq file (Notepad). But it doesnt let me do that and i dont know why.

Comment: There's more to it than that, because it tells you which line the error is on. Please [edit] your post and add the specific details there, not in comments. It doesn't do it now because the code does not compile (because of the error). Which line specifically is causing it? Where is this code located? Where is `UserForm_Nieuw` defined? We can't see any of that from the code you've posted.

Comment: Have edited the post. Img of the error and the line it marks are visible now.

Comment: Images of code are not helpful. There's a list of the many reasons why we do not allow them in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576). Code and error messages are in text.

Comment: Did not intend to post the image for the code, but for the highlighted error. My sincere apologies, Ken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#1` part in `Open pad For Output As #1` etc is a file handle. To obtain a file handle, you need to call [FreeFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function). You cannot just assume that file handle #1 is available at all times.

Try this:

```
Dim iOutputFile As Integer
iOutputFile = FreeFile

If CInt(nieuw.Label1.Caption) = 1 Then
    Open pad For Output As #iOutputFile
Else
    Open pad For Append As #iOutputFile
End If

Write #iOutputFile, CInt(UserForm_Nieuw.Label1.Caption), UserForm_Nieuw.Voornaam, UserForm_Nieuw.Naam, CInt(UserForm_Nieuw.Aantal_kinderen), UserForm_Nieuw.Geboortedatum, UserForm_Nieuw.Startdatum, "---N/A---", diploma, "0", "---N/A---", "---N/A---", "EOR"
Close #iOutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not defined the method of the userform. You failed to compile and the highlight is on the UserForm_Nieuw.Voornaam. So I take that is some sort of input field for the first name? Check whether it is really called that or if it does no have the old default name (something like "Textbox275" or some such like your other elements, e.g. OptionButton1 and 2).

Comment: Hello there. The Textboxes did have generic default names. I have changed all of the textbox names to match the code itself and it now shows the error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. The error highlights the whole Write #1 line.

Comment: @ZombieMence well I am not sure what "Write" is... I would suppose your user-defined function, to which you are passing parametres? So either one of the parametres passed does not correspond to the requirement, or there may be a conversion error in the CInt function (e.g.: CInt(....Label1.Caption)). Also towards the end, you are passing the number 0 to the function within quotation mark, i.e. as a string, not as a number. Is that correct? Last thing - not sure if "#1" would be valid anything in VBA.